# how to filter JSON data in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I have 2 methods to read radio station data: `_readStations` and `_getStationsRemoteJson`

I can filter stations within Firestore data in `_readStations` method as shown in the following code snippet.

But I cannot do the same filtering with JSON data.

How can I filter JSON data?

```
Future<List<Station50K>> _getStationsRemoteJson() async {
  const url = 'JSON URL'; 

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final body = json.decode(response.body);
  final stations = body['data'];

  return stations.map<Station50K>(Station50K.fromJson2).toList();
}

Stream<List<Station>> _readStations() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stations').snapshots().map(
      (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .where((d) =>
              (_favorites.contains(d.data()['id'].toString())) &&
              (d
                      .data()['title']
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                  d
                      .data()['city']
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                  List.from(d.data()['genre']).any((pattern) {
                    return pattern
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase());
                  })))
          .map((doc) => Station.fromJson2(doc.data()))
          .toList());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.

```
Future<List<Station50K>> _getStationsRemoteJson() async {
const url = 'JSON URL';

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final body = json.decode(response.body);
final stations = body['data'];

List<Station50K> list = stations.map<Station50K>(Station50K.fromJson2).toList();

return list
    .where((d) =>
        (_favorites.contains(d.id)) &&
        (d.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            d.city.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
            List.from(d.genres).any((pattern) {
              return pattern
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase());
            })))
    .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `_getStationsRemoteJson()` when returning a list of objects you can first filter it (same as what you have for Firestore `snapshot.docs.where(...)`).

It would look like `stations.map<Station50K>(Station50K.fromJson2).where((object) => object.property == 'searchSomething')`. Probably what's confusing you is that from Firestore, the data you get back is a Map, while here you have already converted it to an object so you can use the object's properties.

Also, for filtering Firestore data there are specific built in methods so you get less data back from server and it costs you a lot less money if used often.[Check it out here.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering)